# How to use images with no background(even there should be no white background to it) using html and css in a website

Tags: html, css

I want the picture in my website to be transparent in background like the png format but when I include the png image the black and white boxes behind the png image appears as it is thus it makes it difficult for me to position the images using CSS because the images have backgrounds thus it looks weird and doesn't properly work with the CSS positioning element.

These are two images in HTML

```
<img class="bottom-cloud" src="cloudwithback.jpg">
<img class="mountain" src="mountain.jpg">
```

CSS CODE:
here is the CSS code to make the background transparent of the images.

```
.top-cloud
{
    height: 200px;
    width: :200px;
    background: transparent; 
}
.bottom-cloud
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.mountain
{
    width: :300px;
    height: 300px;
    background:transparent;
}
```

But it doesn't make the background transparent.

Comment: The images are in .jpg format therefore you can't just remove their "background". Html and css has no the ability to do so.

Comment: css doesn't make your actual image background transparent. It makes the background of the DOM element that holds the image transparent. You have to remove the background in the image file itself.

Comment: can you provide a link to your working code like codepen, jsbin ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that I'm following you so forgive me if I'm a little off topic.

First off, there isn't a piece of software on this planet that can reliably remove background unwanted content from images, you gotta do that manually on Photoshop (or another image editor).

Second, if you're seeing "black and white boxes behind the png image", chances are it was intentional. A lot of images on Google have fake transparent or semi-transparent backgrounds.

Lastly, if you haven't already, learn some image editing. What you're trying to do is really inefficient.

Instead of trying to combine the cloud and Mountain images using HTML and CSS, you're better off getting all that work done in a separate image editing program and processing it there to give you the perfect mountainy clouds in one single image, and that's the image you want.

If you can't get your hands of Photoshop, try GIMP. It's free but it requires a lot of patience to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a proper png image format. You are using jpg. So definitely it is a jpeg not png

Answer (score 0):

your image format is JPG, keep in mind PNG supports transparency while JPG does not. so to convert your image to PNG format with no background, you must remove your background image with the eraser tool or magic eraser tool from photoshop or similar apps, while you are saving your image, choose PNG format. hope that was helpful